# php memcached get failover detection

Tags: php, php-7

I am trying to tell memcached pool failovers. But first am trying only with 1 server

I have the following code

```
$m = new Memcached;
$m->setOption(Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1);
$m->setOption(Memcached::OPT_SERVER_FAILURE_LIMIT, 1);
$m->addServer($somehost,$someport);
function callback($memc, $key, &$value) { echo "Callback for $key " . PHP_EOL; }
$key = 'mk1470838967';
$data = $m->get($key, 'callback');
if (!$data) {
    echo "NOT found $key in cache, result code: " . $m->getResultCode() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Callback should have been called before this";
}
```

So the problem is that when my MC server is running all is fine. I get my data.

BUT when I shutdown my MC server to test failover, the callback is never called and the resultcode is not as expected.

**Output:**

```
NOT found mk1470838967 in cache, result code: 3
Callback should have been called before this
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I understand now that the callback is only for cache misses. But how what about the result code.

Comment: If you shut down you MC server, you cant recieve your callback, am I right?

Comment: hmm so how do I detect if the server is 'down'. Because even the result code is not as expected. I expected it to be MEMCACHED_SERVER_ERROR

Comment: As far as I know the callback is only meaningful on cache misses, not on critical faults. I would have personally expected an exception to be thrown.

Comment: exceptions? I don't think addServer or get throw exceptions